# Added and [replaced with] something

Tags: single-word-requests

I added a bunch of B. In some cases, B replaced A. In other words:

```
I added B, and replaced with B.
```

How can I write that more succinctly?

```
Added and replaced B
```

The above is not correct, because it implies B was replaced with something else.

```
Added and replaced with B
```

The above is ambiguous, as it could be interpreted as "Added with B, and replaced with B". "Added with B" is not something I did.

Is there a single word I could use instead of "replace with"? Is there another way to formulate the sentence without repeating B or adding A?

*Edit:*
More verbosely:

> I added MyNamespace.MyInterfaceFunction to classes which did not already have a similar function, and replaced the similar functions with MyNamespace.MyInterfaceFunction in those that did.

Comment: Of course, "replacement B" implies exactly what I want. Now I just need to turn it into a verb, so... "added and replacementified B"? Turns out verbification does have its uses.

Comment: If you replaced something with B, the addition is implied.

Comment: I introduced B in place of A.  Look we really need to know the context -- cooking?  Chemistry?  Also, do you need to leave it vague, where the reader doesn't know if you added extra B, or only substituted B in place of A?

Comment: @aparente001 Good point. The context is a code commit message for a version control system, where A and B are different versions of a function. Multiple classes were changed. Some classes did not already have the function, and others had an obsolete version of it.

Comment: I replaced A with B where necessary.

Comment: @aparente001 That means that A was sometimes replaced with B and sometimes left alone, which is also not the case. Also, both A and B are typically quite long, so I would like to use only one of either.

Comment: I'd have to see your actual text.  Otherwise I have no way of understanding what's wrong with "I replaced A with B where necessary."

Comment: @aparente001 I've added a more verbose text to the question, I hope that helps.

Comment: What don't you like about your text?

Comment: @aparente001 It's too long. Commit logs have limited space for commit messages, so long ones get truncated.

Comment: Maybe this will work: *Added MyNamespace.MyInterfaceFunction to classes, replacing similar function where one was present.*

Comment: @aparente001 You're on to something. Perhaps even "Added B, replacing similar". You should turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move away from the verb *replaced*, since it results in an ambiguous interpretation.

Instead, use something synonymous but also more explicit in terms of a simple sentence construction:

> I added and **substituted** B.

---

Although really, as a single sentence that describes everything, it should be a bit longer:

> I added and, in some cases, substituted B.

Comment: I like the longer sentence. I also thought "substitute" was a good candidate, but I'm not so sure after reading the [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/substitute):

`The verb "to substitute" can be used transitively in two opposite ways. "To substitute X" may mean either "use X in place of something else", or "use something else in place of X".`

Comment: @Fax I wouldn't rely on Wiktionary. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/substitute) and [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/substitute), for example, both have more useful entries.

Comment: Interesting. The definitions in both dictionaries support your case, but Oxford Dictionaries has a "Usage" section which seems to contradict it: `Despite the potential confusion, the [‘replace someone or something with something else’] use is well established, especially in some scientific contexts and in sport (the top scorer was substituted with almost half an hour still to play), and is now generally regarded as part of normal standard English`

Comment: @Fax Although context can make a difference, I think the specific syntax is also important. It seems that when you say ***was*** substituted* (that specific verb tense) it leads to something that can mean the opposite of the normal use. But if if were to just say *the top player substituted* (without the ***was***) I would interpret it as meaning that the top player came on, not off, the field. But even if it's ambiguous in some situations, the surrounding text should make it clear. In the particular sentence in this question, I don't think there is any ambiguity.